# ListPlot averaging over y-coordinate

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I am trying to plot a list of tuples where each “x” coordinate has multiple corresponding “y” values, sort of like `{{1, 0.5}, {1, 0.7}, {2, 0.8}, {2, 1.0}…}`. I want to create a new list where all the “y” coordinates corresponding to a particular “x” coordinate have been averaged over. So, the previous list would be transformed into `{{1, 0.6}, {2, 0.9}…}`.

What is the cleanest way I can achieve this? I don’t want to write a for-loop or something like that for such a seemingly-trivial thing.

Comment: If your list isn't already sorted then `SortBy[yourlist,First]` will sort by x values. Then `SplitBy[thatresult,First]` will break those into groups of equal x values. Then `Map[Mean,thatnewresult]` will give  you a list of `{x,yavg}` for each of your `x`. Try that, step by step, and see the result. Or `ListPlot[Map[Mean,SplitBy[SortBy[yourlist,First],First]]]` Study that until you think you understand my thinking.

Answer (score 8):

You can also use [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html):

Using the same toy data:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 20;
data = Sort@Transpose[{RandomInteger[5, n], RandomReal[1, n]}];
```

Using `GroupBy`:

```
gb = GroupBy[data, First, {#[[1, 1]], Mean@#[[All, 2]]} &];
ListPlot[{data, Values[gb]}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 PlotTheme -> "OpenMarkersThick"]
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Better answer as per @kglr.

See comment by @kglr (as the larst argument applies to grouped data):

```
gb = GroupBy[data, First, Mean];
ListPlot[{data, Values[gb]}, Joined -> {False, True}, 
 PlotTheme -> "OpenMarkersThick"]
```

Comment: you could also use `GroupBy[data, First, Mean]`

Comment: @kglr of course, much better.

Answer (score 7):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

SeedRandom[1234];

n = 20;

data = Sort@Transpose[
   {RandomInteger[5, n], RandomReal[1, n]}]

(* {{0, 0.113153}, {0, 0.233079}, {0, 0.42294}, {0, 0.875912}, {0, 
  0.87966}, {0, 0.884627}, {0, 0.971018}, {1, 0.754358}, {1, 
  0.95964}, {2, 0.397409}, {2, 0.544858}, {2, 0.87433}, {2, 
  0.922399}, {3, 0.329375}, {4, 0.0542848}, {4, 0.254132}, {4, 
  0.459454}, {5, 0.0637313}, {5, 0.331812}, {5, 0.847531}} *)

data2 = {#[[1, 1]], Mean[#[[All, 2]]]} & /@ GatherBy[data, First]

(* {{0, 0.62577}, {1, 0.856999}, {2, 0.684749}, {3, 0.329375}, {4, 
  0.255957}, {5, 0.414358}} *)

ListPlot[{data, data2},
 Joined -> {False, True},
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

TDIL that [TemporalData[data]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html) does the desired grouping/sorting/averaging when input `data` contains repeated time stamps.

```
data = {{1, a}, {1, b}, {5, w}, {2, u}, {5, x}, {5, y}, {5, z}};

TemporalData[data]["Path"]
```

> ```
>  {{1, (a + b)/2}, {2, u}, {5, 1/4 (w + x + y + z)}}
> ```

Using example data from Bob Hanlon's answer:

```
SeedRandom[1234];
n = 20;
data = Sort @ Transpose[{RandomInteger[5, n], RandomReal[1, n]}];
```

simply use `{data, TemporalData[data]}` in the first argument of `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[{data, TemporalData[data]}, 
 Joined -> {False, True}, 
 PlotTheme -> "OpenMarkersThick", 
 PlotLegends -> {"data", "means"}]
```

[image]

```
means = TemporalData[data]["Path"]
```

> ```
> {{0, 0.62577}, {1, 0.856999}, {2, 0.684749}, {3, 0.329375},   
>  {4, 0.255957}, {5, 0.414358}}
> ```

This matches the data set obtained using methods suggested in Bob Hanlon's and upbdqn's answers and Bill's comment:

```
TemporalData[data]["Path"] ==
 Map[Mean] @ GatherBy[data, First] ==
 Values @ GroupBy[data, First, Mean] ==
 Map[Mean] @ SplitBy[Sort@data, First] ==
 KeyValueMap[List] @ Merge[Mean] @ MapApply[Rule] @ data
```

> ```
> True
> ```